# WALWriteLock on Unlogged table

Tags: postgresql

We've been experiencing some connection spikes on pgbouncer connected to a postgres database. When we query pg_stat_activity during these spikes we see tons of active queries with `wait_event` `WALWriteLock`.

We changed some of our highly inserted tables to unlogged, yet inserts into these tables are still showing up during the spikes with a `wait_event` of `WALWriteLock`. I thought that if a table is unlogged, then inserts into it wouldn't get caught up waiting for `WALWriteLock`. What gives?

Further, any suggestions on how to stop these spikes?

Answer (score 0):

WALWriteLock: accrued by PostgreSQL processes while WAL records are flushed to disk or during a WAL segments switch. synchronous_commit=off removes the wait for disk flush, full_page_writes=off reduces the amount of data to flush.
You can try above also mentioned in dec :-
https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/10/30/postgresql-locking-part-3-lightweight-locks/

Comment: This does not answer the question - why does PG waits for a WALWriteLock in an unlogged table

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is that despite of not writing the table itself to WAL, COMMITs are still written to WAL, and if you make lots of tiny transactions this might show up. See if you can group inserts to smaller number of transactions.